# jQuery Isotope - closing previously opened boxes

Tags: jquery-isotope

I have been searching and searching for an answer to this question but with no luck so far. I have no knowledge of jQuery or Javascript so am pulling my hair out over what could be a simple answer.

I have downloaded jQuery Isotope and am planning to use it as a gallery. Is it possible to automatically close the current expanded box when another one is clicked - returning the previous box to its original size? At the moment when you click on a box it expands, then you click on another one and it expands, with the first one staying expanded.

Thanks in advance,

DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add and remove classes of ".closed" and ".opened" to your elements, i.e. boxes, or just toggle between them, see http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ Then, you probably want to re-isotope your elements with $container.isotope('reLayout');

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a shot. I have just started trying to get into jQuery and Javascript so am way above my head at the moment but Isotope just looked so amazing I had to get my hands on it.